# Python set self-variables by other class using cls?

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-unittest

I wonder if it is possible to set variables of a class by a different class using `cls`?

The story behind it:
I'm writing tests for different purposes but see that one part of the setup is the same as in an already existing class. So I would do the `setUp` by the already existing one:

The original code:

```
class TestBase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.handler = txt.getHandler(hcu.handler3())
        self.curves = self.handler.curves()
        self.arguments = (getInit())
        self.ac = self.connect2DB(self.arguments)
        self.au = AutoUtils()
```

This has worked well so far.
Now in my `TestClient` I'd like to make use of that:

```
from .testsDB import TestBase as tb
class TestClient(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        tb.setUp()
```

And modified in the `TestBase` the `setUp` to the following:

```
@classmethod
def setUp(cls):
    cls.handler = txt.getHandler(hcu.handler3())
    cls.graph = cls.handler.curves()
    cls.argv = (getInit())
    cls.ac = cls.connect2DB(cls.arguments)
    cls.au = AutoUtils()
```

But I'm getting an error as soon as I use one of the values defined in the variables of the `TestClient`-class:

```
def test_Duplicates(self):
    self.testDB = self.ac.connect(self.ac.client, self.arguments[4])
```

With the error:

```
In  test_Duplicate (Curves.tests_client.TestClient) :

 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/qohelet/Curves/tests_client.py", line 49, in test_Duplicate
    self.testDB = self.ac.connect(self.ac.client, self.arguments[4])
AttributeError: 'TestClient' object has no attribute 'ac'
```

Is it actually possible what I'm trying?

EDIT:
After writing this and seeing the answers I did another review. Yes indeed there is a circular issue I'm having.

`TestBase` has the function `connect2DB` which will be executed on `setUp`.
If it refers to itself (as in the original) it's fine.
If I replace the self with `cls` it will try to execute `TestClient.connect2DB` in the `setUp` - which does not exist. So it would require self again as putting `connect2DB` into `TestClient` is not an option.

How to solve that?

Comment: You should review your architecture, same code in different classes is a good reason to apply inheritance.

Comment: btw what is `tj.setUp()`?

Comment: @quamrana - a typo. Corrected already. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @OlvinRoght I think that's much closer to what I originally intended. Thank you. I'll redo it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely your new class should just inherit the `setup()`?

```
from .testsDB import TestBase as tb
class TestClient(tb):
    def test_Duplicates(self):
        self.testDB = self.ac.connect(self.ac.client, self.arguments[4])
```

The whole point of inheritance is that you don't modify what you inherit from. Your new class should just make use of what is supplied. That is why inheritance is sometimes called programming by difference.

Comment: Correct, yes. Olvin Roght stated the same. Thank you. As it was "work-in-progress" I didn't rethink the whole architecture after creating the Client-Class